# How to derive this formula?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

as far as i know the range of an obliquely projected body which is projected with a velocity of **u** with some angle $\theta$ with the horizontal under the action of gravity is
R=$u^2sin2\theta$/g by which we can calculate the range of projected body when it comes to the same level of the point of projection

but how to calculate the remaining distance which it covered below the point of projection

i got this formula on the web but i cant prove this

[image]

Can any one help me by suggesting me what concept I am missing to calculate the range?

Comment: What have you tried? You know the acceleration (from gravity) at every point, and you have the starting velocity and point, so you can simply solve the equation of motion. Where's your problem with that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes acceleration is same throughout the motion but to calculate the distance between two collinear we must know the velocities between those points

Comment: find the range at the same level as B and then find the range from the last point at that level to the final point below. You know the horizontal components of velocity. Add the two ranges.

Comment: @learner +1 for this comment but how to find out the velocity along y-axis at the point b where the particle reaches same level of point of projection

Comment: when it reaches the same level, by symmetry you can find the velocity.

Comment: @learner you mean the velocities are perpendicular to each other or they are equal to each other ?????

Comment: initial and final vertical velocities and hence the velocity at the level B are equal.

Comment: @learner thanks it helped now i can handle the issue in either ways

Comment: @Qmechanic i don't think that i have asked a homework question  instead i asked a particular concept

Comment: I know the question got answered *and* closed already, but I strongly suggest picking up a book on classical mechanics. I mean, don't let it discourage you (really!) but this is very basic stuff: you know the acceleration vector $\mathbf{a}$ (at all times), the initial velocity vector $\mathbf{V}$, and the initial position doesn't really matter (but the origin is often chosen). From this information you can write down $a_x(t)$, $a_y(t)$, $v_x(t)$, $v_y(t)$, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. Using the notation of your picture, your question just boils down to: what is $x(t_1)$, if $y(t_1)=-Yi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [page](http://www.splung.com/content/sid/2/page/projectiles) (equation 10, 11 and 12). It will provide the steps needed to show that the equation you have is correct.

Comment: in the case which i am talking about the body is projected from a tower which is not similar to the case shown in your source

Comment: You did not go down to equation 10. Look at it closely, you will see that the levels are different. From the paragraph above "If the projectile is fired at some height h_0 above the ground that it lands on we must find the additional time that it stays in the air."

Comment: now the point stuck my mind which you are emphasising . thanks for that source and explanation